# Out of memory when restart a code

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

I made a matlab code including some symbolic functions

First I run this code, it gives me a result.

But trying to run the same code again, Out of memory message comes up.

Does anybody have an idea to solve this problem?

Below is my code.

```
clc;
clear;
tic;
rng('shuffle');
p=2; % AR order
yr=normrnd(0,1,1000,1);
T=max(size(yr));
for k=25:35;
    intnum=k/10;
    fore=100;
    int=((max(yr)-min(yr))/intnum);
    fin=T-fore;

    % Initial setting matrix
    y_T1=zeros(fore,1);
    y_fore_w=zeros(fore,1); y_diff_w=zeros(fore,1);
    y_fore_o=zeros(fore,1);y_diff_o=zeros(fore,1);
    y_fore_f=zeros(fore,1);y_diff_f=zeros(fore,1);
    y_fore_wl=zeros(fore,1);y_diff_wl=zeros(fore,1);
    y_fore_m=zeros(fore,1);y_diff_m=zeros(fore,1);
    y_gap=zeros(fore,1);
    for e=fin:T-1  ;
        y_1=yr(p+1:e);x_1=yr(p:e-1);x_2=yr(p-1:e-2);
        A=[y_1 x_1 x_2];
        st=1;
        ye=yr(st:e);
        coordinate = zeros(length(y_1), 3); % Giving new indices to A
        y_1_diff=max(y_1)-min(y_1);x_1_diff=max(x_1)-min(x_1);x_2_diff=max(x_2)-min(x_2);
        y_1_int=y_1_diff/int;x_1_int=x_1_diff/int;x_2_int=x_2_diff/int;
        y_1_int_num=round(y_1_int);x_1_int_num=round(x_1_int);x_2_int_num=round(x_2_int);
        for i=1:y_1_int_num;
            coordinate(A(:,1) >= (i-1)*int+min(A(:,1)) & A(:,1) < i*int+min(A(:,1)), 1) = i ; % Terrific idea for some conditions in ROW
        end
        for i=1:x_1_int_num;
            coordinate(A(:,2) >= (i-1)*int+min(A(:,2)) & A(:,2) < i*int+min(A(:,2)), 2) = i ; % Terrific idea for some conditions in ROW
        end
        for i=1:x_2_int_num;
            coordinate(A(:,3) >= (i-1)*int+min(A(:,3)) & A(:,3) < i*int+min(A(:,3)), 3) = i; % Terrific idea for some conditions in ROW
        end
        sz=[y_1_int_num x_1_int_num x_2_int_num];
        nucu=max(sz)^(p+1);
        y_int_sub_num=zeros(nucu,1); % Number of frequency
        yfunc=cell(nucu,1);  % Cell of functions
        c=1:max(sz);
        C=combvec(c,c,c)'; % Generate a reference matrix to coordinate
        d=sortrows(C);
        syms c b1 b2;
        for i=1:nucu;
            a=ismember(coordinate, d(i,:), 'rows');
            s=sum(a);
            y_int_sub_num(i)=s;
            B=A(a,:);
            func=symfun((B(:,1)-c-b1*B(:,2)-b2*B(:,3)).^2, [c,b1,b2]);
            yfunc1=sum(func);
            yfunc{i}=yfunc1*y_int_sub_num(i);
            clear func; clear yfunc1;
        end
        yfuncs=symfun(sym('f(c,b1,b2)'),[c,b1,b2]);
        for j=1:nucu;
            yfuncs=yfuncs+yfunc{j};
        end
        yfuncs= yfuncs-'f(c,b1,b2)';
        y_trans = matlabFunction(yfuncs,'Vars',{[c;b1;b2]});


        % WLLS
        options = optimset('Algorithm','Interior-point',...
            'TolFun',1e-8, 'MaxFunEvals',1000000,'MaxIter',1000000);  % Set option
        [b_w,fval] = fminsearch(y_trans, [0;0;0], options);
        % OLS
        c=ones(T-p,1);y_c=zeros(T-p,4);
        y_c(:,1)=yr(p+1:T);y_c(:,2)=c;y_c(:,3)=yr(2:end-(p-1));y_c(:,4)=yr(1:end-2);
        [b_0,bint_0,e_0,rint,stats] = regress(y_c(:,1), y_c(:,2:4));
        % WLS
        e_0_w=e_0.^2/sum(e_0.^2); %normalization required for Matlab
        [bw,se_bw] = lscov(y_c(:,1), y_c(:,2:4), e_0_w);
        % FGLS_iterated
        [bf, Sigma] = lscov(y_c(:,1), y_c(:,2:4), e_0_w);
        %     [bf, Sigma]=fglsi(y_c(:,1), y_c(:,3), y_c(:,4), y_c(:,3));
        % MLE
        [b_m, b_mm, mu, sig] = regress(y_c(:,1), y_c(:,2:4)); % Since error, OL

        % Foracast and Differences
        n=e-(fin-1);
        y_T1(n)=yr(e+1);
        y_fore_w(n)=b_w(1)+b_w(2)*ye(end)+b_w(3)*ye(end-1);y_diff_w(n)=y_T1(n)-y_fore_w(n);
        y_fore_o(n)=b_0(1)+b_0(2)*ye(end)+b_0(3)*ye(end-1);y_diff_o(n)=y_T1(n)-y_fore_o(n);
        y_fore_wl(n)=bw(1)+bw(2)*ye(end)+bw(3)*ye(end-1);;y_diff_wl(n)=y_T1(n)-y_fore_wl(n);
        y_fore_f(n)=bf(1)+bf(2)*ye(end)+bf(3)*ye(end-1);;y_diff_f(n)=y_T1(n)-y_fore_f(n);
        y_fore_m(n)=b_m(1)+b_m(2)*ye(end)+b_m(3)*ye(end-1);;y_diff_m(n)=y_T1(n)-y_fore_m(n);
        y_gap(n)=abs(y_diff_w(n))-abs(y_diff_o(n));ygap(n)=(y_gap(n)<=0);
    end
    toc
    a=1;filename =  [ 'comp', num2str(a), '.mat' ];
    save(filename);
    if mean(y_diff_w.^2) <=mean(y_diff_o.^2)
        [int  mean(y_diff_w.^2)]
        beep;
    end
    z1=zeros(y_1_int+1,1);
    for i=1:y_1_int+1;
        z=(yr>=(i-1)*int+min(yr) &  yr<i*int+min(yr));
        z1(i)=sum(z);
    end
    z1
end
sort(yr)
[max(yr) min(yr)]
```

Comment: well, do you have a `clear` in the beginning? are you creating more and more variables each time you run it?

Comment: Could you post your code so we don't need to guess what you're doing and how you get the error?

Comment: @Ander Biguri Surely I start with 'clear'.

Comment: @mikkola I added that.